# Recursive javascript function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have this array of objects which I'm trying to parse so I can get the fields from one instance I have

```
const obj = [{
  'name': 'A',
  'type': 'group',
  'fields': [a_bunch_of_objs],
  'instances': [
    {
      name: 'AA',
      'type': 'group',
      'fields': [a_bunch_of_objs],
      'instances': [
        {
          'name': 'AAA',
          'type': 'group',
          'fields': [a_bunch_of_objs],
          'instances': []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  'name': 'B',
  'type': 'bla',
  'instances': []
}];
```

I have a recursive function

```
getInstanceFields: function(form_fields, instance_name) {
    var self = this;
    form_fields.forEach(function(field) {
      if (field.field_type === 'group') {
        field.instances.forEach(function(instance) {
          if (instance.name === instance_name) {
            return instance.fields;
          } else {
            return self.getInstanceFields(instance.fields, instance_name);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  },
```

which I'm calling like this: getInstanceFields(obj, 'name_to_search_for');

Problem is that if I add a console log before returning `instance.fields` I see the correct values, but if the actual returned result is `undefined`.

Any clues as to what I'm missing here?

Comment: forEach and returning a value ... what do you want with that value?

Comment: `getInstanceFields` doesn't return anything; therefore the implicit `undefined`. The `return` statements are inside a different/nested function and apply only to that function.